# How do I check if a given user ID has authenticated my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API and want to check if a user has authenticated my Facebook app by user ID. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use:

```
SELECT is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid=USER_ID
```

This should return:

```
[
  {
    "is_app_user": true
  }
]
```

If the user has logged in to your application.

Comment: logged in? I thought he asked to check if the user has the certain app installed or not. is this the same check?

Comment: by logged in he meant an user who has installed the app

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on ifaour's answer, in PHP this query would look something like this:

```
<?php
    $facebook = new Facebook(
        'appID' => YOUR_APP_ID, 
        'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET
    );

    $result = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => "SELECT is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid=$user_id"
    ));

    $is_installed = $result[0]['is_app_user'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can batch multiple requests together and avoid using FQL.**

Assuming you have already logged into facebook and set the access token to the application access token, you can do this:

```
$batch = array();
foreach($friendArray AS $friend) {
    $batch[] = array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'relative_url' => '/' . $friend . '?fields=installed'
    );
}

FB()->useApplicationAccessToken();
$batchResponse = FB()->facebook()->api('?batch='.json_encode($batch), 'POST');
```

Then you can process the batch response with code like this:

```
$installedUsers = array();
$notInstalledUsers = array();
foreach ($batchResponse AS $response) {
    $body = json_decode($response['body'], true);
    if (!isset($body['id']))
        continue;

    $id = $body['id'];
    if (isset($body['installed']))
        $installedUsers[] = $id;
    else
        $notInstalledUsers[] = $id;
}
```